# How to add hyperlink to individual countries? AMCharts

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404, amcharts

I am trying to attach a link to another page when an individual country is clicked. I have added one url link so far to Algeria (id: DZ):

```
{ "data": [{"id": "DZ"}], "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algeria" }
```

However when I click the map it returns a 404 not found error, it also converts the address to %7Burl%7D. I am running my site on localhost. I have tried adding both an actual website (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algeria) and the path to one of my local html file pages but both return the exact same error. Is this occurring because i'm running localhost or because my code is wrong?

The function used to link url when country is clicked:

```
mapPolygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
ev.target.series.chart.url = "{url}";
});
```

Also the link isn't localised to one country on the map, the error occurs when anywhere on the map is clicked. How can I make sure each country has its own unique link when I attach them all?

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);

chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldUltra;


chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

chart.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();

var homeButton = new am4core.Button();
homeButton.events.on("hit", function() {
  chart.goHome();
});

homeButton.icon = new am4core.Sprite();
homeButton.padding(7, 5, 7, 5);
homeButton.width = 30;
homeButton.icon.path = "M16,8 L14,8 L14,16 L10,16 L10,10 L6,10 L6,16 L2,16 L2,8 L0,8 L8,0 L16,8 Z M16,8";
homeButton.marginBottom = 10;
homeButton.parent = chart.zoomControl;
homeButton.insertBefore(chart.zoomControl.plusButton);

chart.homeZoomLevel = 4;
chart.homeGeoPoint = {
  longitude: 16.5,
  latitude: 3.8
};


var groupData = [{
    "data": [{
      "id": "DZ",
      "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algeria"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "AO"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "BJ"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "BW"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "BF"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "BI"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "CM"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "CV"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "CF"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "KM"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "CD"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "DJ"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "EG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "GQ"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ER"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ET"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "GA"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "GM"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "GH"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "GN"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "GW"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "CI"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "KE"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "LS"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "LR"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "LY"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "MG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "MW"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ML"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "MR"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "MU"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "MA"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "MZ"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "NA"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "NE"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "NG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "CG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "RE"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "RW"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SH"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ST"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SN"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SC"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SL"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SO"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ZA"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SS"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SD"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SZ"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "TZ"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "TG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "TN"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "UG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "EH"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "YT"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ZM"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ZW"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "TD"
    }]
  }
];


var excludedCountries = ["AQ"];


groupData.forEach(function(group) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
  series.name = group.name;
  series.useGeodata = true;
  var includedCountries = [];
  group.data.forEach(function(country) {
    includedCountries.push(country.id);
    excludedCountries.push(country.id);
  });
  series.include = includedCountries;

  series.fill = am4core.color("#fff");


  series.setStateOnChildren = true;
  var seriesHoverState = series.states.create("hover");


  var mapPolygonTemplate = series.mapPolygons.template;
  mapPolygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
  mapPolygonTemplate.fillOpacity = 1;
  mapPolygonTemplate.nonScalingStroke = false;
  mapPolygonTemplate.stroke = am4core.color("#878787");
  mapPolygonTemplate.strokeWidth = 0.2;
  mapPolygonTemplate.strokeOpacity = 0.5;
  mapPolygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}";

  mapPolygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
    ev.target.series.chart.url = "{url}";
  });

  var hoverState = mapPolygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
  hoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#a3cc88");

  series.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(group.data));

});



var worldSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
var worldSeriesName = "world";
worldSeries.name = worldSeriesName;
worldSeries.useGeodata = true;
worldSeries.exclude = excludedCountries;
worldSeries.fillOpacity = 0.3;
worldSeries.mapPolygons.template.nonScalingStroke = true;

worldSeries.mapPolygons.template.stroke = worldSeries.mapPolygons.template.fill;
worldSeries.mapPolygons.template.strokeWidth = 0;
```

```css
html body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100vh;
  border: solid #000 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chartdiv"></div>

<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/worldUltra.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [propertyFields](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Property_fields) to refer to the URL in your data as in `mapPolygonTemplate.propertyFields.url = "url";`.

Please check the working example below:

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);

chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldUltra;


chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

chart.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();

var homeButton = new am4core.Button();
homeButton.events.on("hit", function() {
  chart.goHome();
});

homeButton.icon = new am4core.Sprite();
homeButton.padding(7, 5, 7, 5);
homeButton.width = 30;
homeButton.icon.path = "M16,8 L14,8 L14,16 L10,16 L10,10 L6,10 L6,16 L2,16 L2,8 L0,8 L8,0 L16,8 Z M16,8";
homeButton.marginBottom = 10;
homeButton.parent = chart.zoomControl;
homeButton.insertBefore(chart.zoomControl.plusButton);

chart.homeZoomLevel = 4;
chart.homeGeoPoint = {
  longitude: 16.5,
  latitude: 3.8
};


var groupData = [{
    "data": [{
      "id": "DZ",
      "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algeria"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "AO"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "BJ"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "BW"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "BF"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "BI"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "CM"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "CV"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "CF"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "KM"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "CD"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "DJ"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "EG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "GQ"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ER"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ET"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "GA"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "GM"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "GH"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "GN"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "GW"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "CI"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "KE"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "LS"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "LR"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "LY"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "MG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "MW"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ML"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "MR"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "MU"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "MA"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "MZ"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "NA"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "NE"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "NG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "CG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "RE"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "RW"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SH"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ST"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SN"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SC"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SL"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SO"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ZA"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SS"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SD"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "SZ"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "TZ"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "TG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "TN"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "UG"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "EH"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "YT"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ZM"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "ZW"
    }]
  },
  {
    "data": [{
      "id": "TD"
    }]
  }
];


var excludedCountries = ["AQ"];


groupData.forEach(function(group) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
  series.name = group.name;
  series.useGeodata = true;
  var includedCountries = [];
  group.data.forEach(function(country) {
    includedCountries.push(country.id);
    excludedCountries.push(country.id);
  });
  series.include = includedCountries;

  series.fill = am4core.color("#fff");


  series.setStateOnChildren = true;
  var seriesHoverState = series.states.create("hover");


  var mapPolygonTemplate = series.mapPolygons.template;
  mapPolygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
  mapPolygonTemplate.fillOpacity = 1;
  mapPolygonTemplate.nonScalingStroke = false;
  mapPolygonTemplate.stroke = am4core.color("#878787");
  mapPolygonTemplate.strokeWidth = 0.2;
  mapPolygonTemplate.strokeOpacity = 0.5;
  mapPolygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}";
  mapPolygonTemplate.propertyFields.url = "url";
  // mapPolygonTemplate.urlTarget = "_blank";

  // mapPolygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  //   ev.target.series.chart.url = "{url}";
  // });

  var hoverState = mapPolygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
  hoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#a3cc88");

  series.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(group.data));

});



var worldSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
var worldSeriesName = "world";
worldSeries.name = worldSeriesName;
worldSeries.useGeodata = true;
worldSeries.exclude = excludedCountries;
worldSeries.fillOpacity = 0.3;
worldSeries.mapPolygons.template.nonScalingStroke = true;

worldSeries.mapPolygons.template.stroke = worldSeries.mapPolygons.template.fill;
worldSeries.mapPolygons.template.strokeWidth = 0;
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100vh;
  border: solid #000 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chartdiv"></div>

<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/worldUltra.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
```